# Error Installing PostgreSQL on Amazon EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install PostgreSQL on my micro Amazon EC2 instance through the commands:

```
sudo su

yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs
```

except it returns the following error message:

> yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs
>   Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
>   Setting up Install Process
>   https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 407"
>   Trying other mirror.
>   Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: pgdg93. Please verify its path and try again

I have been trying to figure out the cause of this error to no prevail, could anyone shine some light on potential problems on my instance that I could try correcting?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: read this http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/#yum and search for help on how to use yum and how it works

Comment: I just tried "sudo yum upgrade" and "sudo yum update" and both return the same error message as in original question. Though this is kind of odd to me since that wouldn't be directly referencing the directory on postgresql.org .

Comment: which AMI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the steps here. This should work
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation